# Regexp to match logcat brief format with g_regex_match_simple

Tags: android, regex, glib

I'm trying to write a wireshark dissector for logcat logs in various text formats.

To do it I need to detect which type of logcat I'm reading, and then get the respectable parts extracted. I thought that using a regular expression would do the trick, but apparently it doesn't.

Here is my regular expression:

```
[IVDWE]/.*\(\s*[0-9]*\):\s.*
```

As it should be Perl compatibile I tried it with Perl from command line and it seems to work. Yet when loading a line, ex.

```
I/bdAddrLoader(  184): option : f=/persist/bluetooth/.bdaddr
```

with `g_regex_match_simple`, the expression does not match from opening round brace. I tried escaping it with 1-4 `\`, but it didn't work.

Edit:
Turns out that I've tried `\`,'\`,and `\\\\` versions, but missed somehow `\\`...

Comment: Not sure how `g_regex_match_simple`'s delimiters work..but, if they use the common `/` delimiter, then you will need to escape the `/` with `\/`.

Comment: Try compiling the regular expression with `g_regex_new` first.

Comment: @Sam: As I wrote the part until opening round brace (`[IVDWE]/.*`) is working. The problem starts with the brace opening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me with two backslashes:

```
#include <glib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  gboolean res = g_regex_match_simple ("[IVDWE]/.*\\(\\s*[0-9]*\\):\\s.*",
                                       "I/bdAddrLoader(  184): option : f=/persist/bluetooth/.bdaddr",
                                       0, 0);
  g_message ("%s", res ? "true" : "false");

  return 0;
}
```