# Regexp to match http header format with "g_regex_match_simple"

Tags: c, http-headers, glib

I'm trying to match HTTP header format in C using glib's `g_regex_match_simple`:

```
static const char header_regex[] = "/([\\w-]+): (\\w+)";

...

const char header[] = "Test: header1";
if (g_regex_match_simple(header_regex, header, 0, 0))
{
    headers[index] = g_strdup(header);
    index++;
}
else
{
    error_setg(errp, "%s is not a valid http header format", header);
    goto cleanup;
}
```

I'm getting FALSE out of `g_regex_match_simple()` even though "Test: header1" should be valid.

What am I missing?

I tried the answer in
[Regexp to match logcat brief format with g_regex_match_simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740582/regexp-to-match-logcat-brief-format-with-g-regex-match-simple?newreg=5ca83175302a4968bd4ecb09bf099879)
but it didn't work for me.

Ideas?

Comment: You have a `slash` character in your pattern and do not have a `slash` character in the test string.

Comment: Thanks! you're right! I copied the regex string with the first `slash` instead of omitting it...

Comment: You probably should mark the qustion as accepted, if it does solve your specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are compiled with `clang -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include youe_file.c -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>

static const char header_regex[] = "([\\w-]+): (\\w+)";


int main()
{
const char header[] = "Test: header1";
if (g_regex_match_simple(header_regex, header, 0, 0)){
 printf("+\n");}
else {
    printf("-\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

And it gives a positive match. The difference were in `regexp` pattern. I've removed a slash.

Original string `static const char header_regex[] = "/([\\w-]+): (\\w+)";`
needs to be `static const char header_regex[] = "([\\w-]+): (\\w+)";`

```
                                   ^
                                   |
                                no slash here
```